# Subclipse: Problem comparing php files

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

Is anyone else having problems comparing php files in subclipse? Whenever I attempt to compare my working file with the one in the repository, I get a blank screen or it hangs with the message "Initializing...". It doesn't work regardless of what perspective I'm in or if I compare with the base revision or the latest from the repository.

Comparing java files works fine and comparing php files with the command line svn utility also works, which is what I use as a workaround.

I'm using eclipse 3.6.1 with subclipse 1.6.17. My subversion repository is google code.

Comment: Works fine for me. Is upgrading your eclipse version an option? 3.1.6 is pretty old now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug mentioned here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326194 that has a workaround. Apparently it will be fixed in the next release, but you can add the update site http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/2.2/milestones to your eclipse installation and it should fix your compare editor.

Comment: I just updated my PDT to the latest version and the problems appear to have been resolved.